# Tensorflow 2 subclassed model retracing error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am implementing a tensorflow model using the keras subclassing api, as mentioned in a previous post here:

[Tensorflow Model Subclassing Mutli-Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743161/tensorflow-model-subclassing-mutli-input)

I am running into an error that is slowing my entire system, where it is retracing but I cannot narrow down where this error occurs, I do not use @tf.function anywhere in my code. I am looking for support on narrowing down the location of the error or how to solve it.

The exact error is:

> WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr. W0127
>   15:31:00.867754 4815351232 def_function.py:586] 5 out of the last 6
>   calls to .distributed_function at 0x157208d08> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the
>   excessive number of tracings is likely due to passing python objects
>   instead of tensors. Also, tf.function has
>   experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes
>   that can avoid unnecessary retracing. Please refer to
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args
>   and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for more
>   details.

Looking into it further disabling eager execution is throwing this warning that may be a causing factor:

> 2020-01-27 16:11:42.781884: W tensorflow/c/c_api.cc:326] Operation
>   '{name:'basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while'
>   id:542 op device:{} def:{{{node
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while}}
>   = While[T=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_VARIANT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_VARIANT, DT_VARIANT, DT_VARIANT, DT_VARIANT, DT_VARIANT],
>   _lower_using_switch_merge=true, _num_original_outputs=52, body=basic_parsing_model_time_distributed_bidirectional_backward_gru_while_body_708[],
>   cond=basic_parsing_model_time_distributed_bidirectional_backward_gru_while_cond_707[],
>   output_shapes=[[], [], [], [], [?,32], ..., [], [], [], [], []],
>   parallel_iterations=32](basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/loop_counter, basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/maximum_iterations,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/time,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/TensorArrayV2_1,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/zeros,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/strided_slice_1,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/backward_gru/bias,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/backward_gru/kernel,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/backward_gru/recurrent_kernel,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_1,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_2,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_3,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_4,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_5,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_6,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_7,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_8,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_9,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_10,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_11,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_12,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_13,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_14,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_15,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_16,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_17,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_18,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_19,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_20,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_21,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_22,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_23,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_24,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_25,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_26,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_27,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_28,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_29,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_30,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_31,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_32,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_33,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_34,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_35,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_36,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_37,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_38,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_39,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_40,
>   basic_parsing_model/time_distributed/bidirectional/backward_gru/while/EmptyTensorList_41)}}'
>   was changed by setting attribute after it was run by a session. This
>   mutation will have no effect, and will trigger an error in the future.
>   Either don't modify nodes after running them or create a new session.
>   2020-01-27 16:11:46.854955: W
>   tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error
>   occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled:
>   Operation was cancelled