# How to train Keras model with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feed

I want to train a Keras model with multiple inputs. I want to use the first input for training the model, but the second and the third inputs are variables which must be used during the training of the first input. I could not use the `tf.Variable` for using the second and the third inputs which are fixed during the training because it showed the error: `You must feed a placeholder`. So, I want to feed them using `tf.keras`. I changed the shape of the second and the third inputs to be similar to the first one. Then, I concatenate them using:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([data, masks_rep, ind_rep], axis=2)
```

Then, for retrieving them in the model, I wrote:

```
Inputs_t = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_length, 3*charset_length))
x, m_k_expand, ind_k_expand = tf.split(Inputs_t, num_or_size_splits=3,  axis=1)
```

But it changes the dimensions of the layers from `charset_length` to `3*charset_length`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the subclasses to use additional variables by using `tf.Variable`. `tf.Variable` easily leads bugs when it is used with `tf.keras.layers`. But using subclasses prevents bugs. More examples are provided here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743161/tensorflow-model-subclassing-mutli-input)